# Converting ObjectID from a string?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

How do I reverse this :

```
NSURL *uriID = [[obj objectID] URIRepresentation];
NSString *stringID = [uriID absoluteString];
```

to get back to objectID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use persistent store coordinator.

```
NSURL *uriId = ...;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = ...;
NSManagedObjectID *objectId =  [coordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:urlId];
```

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track.

Note to self : 

get coordinator : 

     NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:[NSURL URLWithString:identifier]];

and keep in mind that you have to persist object before you get the objectID : 

[core-data error 133000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637444/core-data-existingobjectwithiderror-causes-error-133000)